# 2D: How do I transform a velocity vector for a circle into normal and tangent components in collision with another ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's say that I have two circles that collide somewhere on a 2d-plane. Each ball has their own velocity vector consisting of an $x$-part and a $y$-part. Let's assume that I know the velocities and positions of each ball.

In order to calculate the velocities of the balls after their collision, I need to find out how fast each ball is travelling in the direction that is right towards the center of the other ball (let's call this the normal direction). I also need to know how fast each ball is travelling perpendicularly to the normal direction (let's call this the tangent direction).

When I know these two parts of the velocity of each ball, I can assume that the normal components of the velocities will behave in accordance with the head-on collision laws (right?) and that the tangent components remain the same, since no force is acting in that direction.

How can I calculate the normal and tangent components of each ball's velocity?

Answer (score 1):

I think your difficulty is finding the orientation in which the circles collide. If you have determined that the circles will collide then you will know the geometry of the collision.

You need to find the velocity of one circle relative to the other. Suppose circle B is stationary. Draw a circle around the centre of B equal to the sum of radii of the two circles. This is the circle of closest approach. Then subtract the velocity vector $\vec{v_B}$ from $\vec{v_A}$ to get the relative velocity $\vec{v_{AB}}$ of A relative to B. When you apply $\vec{v_{AB}}$ to the initial position $\vec{r_{AB}}$ of A relative to B, then the point at which the velocity vector first crosses the circle of closest approach gives you the orientation of the circles when they collide. It is then simple to resolve the relative velocity vector $\vec{v_{AB}}$ along and perpendicular to the line joining the centres.
[image]

If you are developing a game or simulation, an [internet search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=game+development+circle-circle+collision&oq=game+development+circle-circle+collision&gs_l=psy-ab.3...141924.149971.0.151120.16.16.0.0.0.0.115.1168.13j1.14.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.320I8cuYvpg) will give you several tutorials which discuss algorithms for detecting and handling collisions.